# How to draw the three triangle in single page using canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

```js
function areaval() {
    var equation = $('#number').val();
    var secod = $('#acure').val();
    var thrd = $('#pmet').val();
    var frd = $('#cmet').val();
    var a = Math.abs(parseInt(equation * secod) );
    var d = Math.abs(a/2);
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Area=(1/2)*b*h<br><br>A="+d+"cm2";
    document.getElementById("step4.1").innerHTML = "step1=(1/2)*"+equation+"*"+secod;
    var f= Math.abs(parseInt(equation) + parseInt(thrd) + parseInt(frd));
    document.getElementById("result2.2").innerHTML = "Perimeter=a+b+c<br><br>P="+f+"cm2";
    document.getElementById("step4.6").innerHTML = "step2="+equation+"+"+thrd+"+"+frd; 
    $('input').val('');
    return false;
}

function rightang() {
    var givenone = $('#oppsite').val();
    var giventwo = $('#adjacent').val();
    var giventhree = $('#hyper').val();
    var givenhig = $('#hidgt').val();
    var agive = Math.abs(parseInt(givenone * givenhig) );
    var ragive = Math.abs((agive)/2);
    document.getElementById("raitresult").innerHTML = "Area=(1/2)*b*h<br><br>A="+ragive+"cm2";
    document.getElementById("step5.1").innerHTML = "step1=(1/2)*"+givenone+"*"+givenhig;
    var subperi = Math.abs((2*givenone)+(2*giventwo));
    var rtsub = Math.sqrt(subperi);
    var srtadd = Math.floor(parseInt(givenone)+parseInt(giventwo));
    var finres = Math.floor(parseInt(rtsub)+parseInt(srtadd));
    document.getElementById("periresult2").innerHTML = "Perimeter=a+b+c<br><br>P="+finres+"cm2";
    document.getElementById("step5.5").innerHTML = "step2="+givenone+"+"+giventwo+"+"+giventhree;
    var hysid = Math.floor(parseInt(finres)/parseInt(giventwo));
    var hyang = Math.abs(2*parseInt(hysid));
    document.getElementById("periresult3").innerHTML = "Angle of a=A*2/b<br><br>angle="+hyang+"degree";
    document.getElementById("step5.8").innerHTML = "step3="+hysid+"*"+"2"+"/"+givenone;
    $('input').val('');
    return false;
}

function obtuseang() {
    var oppavall = $('#oppsite6').val();
    var oppbval = $('#oppsite7').val();
    var obtont = $('#oppsite1').val();
    var obttwo = $('#oppsite2').val();
    var obttriagle = Math.abs(parseInt(obtont * obttwo ) );
    var obtval = Math.abs((obttriagle)/2);
    document.getElementById("raitresult43").innerHTML = "Area=(1/2)*b*h<br><br>A="+obtval+"cm2";
    document.getElementById("step6.1").innerHTML = "step1=(1/2)*"+obtont+"*"+obttwo;
    var obtperi = Math.abs(parseInt(oppavall)+parseInt(oppbval)+parseInt(obtont));
    document.getElementById("obtuseresult").innerHTML = "Perimeter=a+b+c<br><br>P="+obtperi+"cm2";
    document.getElementById("stepfine").innerHTML = "step2="+oppavall+"+"+oppbval+"+"+obtont;
    $('input').val('');
    return false;
}
```

```css
#equilateral-try {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 128px solid transparent;
    border-right: 48px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 95px solid black;
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:100px;
}

#coverbox {
    position:absolute;
    top:calc(8%);
    left:calc(3%);
    width:300px;
    height:500px;
}

#equilateral-try:after {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-left: 110px solid transparent;
    border-right: 40px solid transparent;
    content: "";
    border-bottom: 80px solid #fff;
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:-110px;
    z-index:1;
}

#strightline {
    position:absolute;
    left:66%;
    top:22%;
    z-index:2;
}

#right-try { 
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-bottom: 100px solid black; 
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
    position:absolute;
    top:16%;
    left:45%;   
}

#coverbox11 {
    position:absolute;
    top:calc(8% );
    left:calc(30% );
    width:300px;
    height:500px;
}

#right-try:after { 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    content: "";   
    border-bottom: 85px solid #fff; 
    border-right: 85px solid transparent;
    position:absolute;
    top:12px;
    left:6px;
    z-index:6; 
}

#obtuse-try {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 100px solid black; 
    border-left: 140px solid transparent; 
    position:absolute;
    top:17%;
    left:20%;
}

#coverbox12 {
    position:absolute;
    top:calc(8% );
    left:calc(65% );
    width:300px;
    height:500px;
}

#obtuse-try:after {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    content: "";   
    border-bottom: 80px solid #fff; 
    border-left: 120px solid transparent; 
    position:absolute;
    top:14px;
    left:-125px;
    z-index:8;
}

#strightline3 {
    position:absolute;
    left:68.8%;
    top:16%;
    z-index:9;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="angleoftriangle.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="angleoftriangle.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="coverbox">
    <div id="equilateral-try">
    </div>
    <form id="text" onsubmit="return areaval()">
        <p id="heading1"style="position:absolute;top:8%;left:20%;font-size:22px;color:black;">Acute Triangle</p>
        <p id="heading5"style="position:absolute;top:42%;left:20%;font-size:20px;color:black;">abc<90deg.</p>
        <input type="text" value ="" id="number" style="position:absolute;width:8%;height:4%;left:60%;top:40%;outline:none;border:none;font-size:25px;background-color:transparent;" placeholder="b"required>
        <input type="text" value ="" id="acure" style="position:absolute;width:8%;height:4%;left:78%;top:31%;outline:none;border:none;font-size:25px;z-index:4;background-color:transparent;" placeholder="h"required>
        <input type="text" value ="" id="pmet" style="position:absolute;width:8%;height:4%;left:42%;top:25%;outline:none;border:none;font-size:25px;z-index:6;background-color:transparent;" placeholder="a"required>
        <input type="text" value ="" id="cmet" style="position:absolute;width:8%;height:4%;left:88%;top:25%;outline:none;border:none;font-size:25px;z-index:5;background-color:transparent;" placeholder="c"required>
        <button style="position:absolute;height:20px;left:70%;top:41%;">sol</button>
    </form>
    <div id="result"style="position:absolute;top:55%;left:20%;font-size:20px;color:#878787;"></div>
    <div id="step4.1"style="position:absolute;top:60%;left:20%;font-size:20px;color:#878787;"></div>
    <div id="result2.2"style="position:absolute;top:68%;left:20%;font-size:20px;color:#878787;"></div>
    <div id="step4.6"style="position:absolute;top:73%;left:20%;font-size:20px;color:#878787;"></div>
    <svg height="16%" width="14%"id="strightline">
        <line x1="30" y1="0" x2="30" y2="105" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:2" />
    </svg>
</div>

<div id="coverbox11">
    <div id="right-try">
    </div>
    <form id="text1" onsubmit="return rightang()">
        <p id="heading1"style="position:absolute;top:7%;left:32%;font-size:22px;color:black;">Rightangle Triangle</p>
        <p id="heading5"style="position:absolute;top:42%;left:43%;font-size:20px;color:black;"> a=90degree.</p>
        <input type="text" value ="" id="oppsite" style="position:absolute;width:8%;height:4%;left:38%;top:23%;outline:none;border:none;font-size:25px;background-color:transparent;" placeholder="a"required>
        <input type="text" value ="" id="hidgt" style="position:absolute;width:8%;height:4%;left:48%;top:23%;outline:none;border:none;font-size:25px;z-index:20;background-color:transparent;" placeholder="h"required>
        <input type="text" value ="" id="adjacent" style="position:absolute;width:8%;height:4%;left:53%;top:37%;outline:none;border:none;font-size:25px;z-index:4;background-color:transparent;" placeholder="b"required>
        <input type="text" value ="" id="hyper" style="position:absolute;width:8%;height:4%;left:68%;top:23%;outline:none;border:none;font-size:25px;z-index:6;background-color:transparent;" placeholder="c"required>
        <button style="position:absolute;height:20px;left:64%;top:38%;">sol</button>
    </form>
    <div id="raitresult"style="position:absolute;top:55%;left:43%;font-size:20px;color:#878787;"></div>
    <div id="step5.1"style="position:absolute;top:60%;left:43%;font-size:20px;color:#878787;"></div>
    <div id="periresult2"style="position:absolute;top:70%;left:43%;font-size:20px;color:#878787;"></div>
    <div id="step5.5"style="position:absolute;top:75%;left:43%;font-size:20px;color:#878787;"></div>
    <div id="periresult3"style="position:absolute;top:85%;left:43%;font-size:20px;color:#878787;"></div>
    <div id="step5.8"style="position:absolute;top:90%;left:43%;font-size:20px;color:#878787;"></div>
</div>

<div id="coverbox12">
    <div id="obtuse-try">
    </div>
    <svg height="15%" width="15%"id="strightline3">
        <path id="lineAB" d="M 100 150 l 70 -200" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
    </svg>
    <form id="text2" onsubmit="return obtuseang()">
        <p id="heading16"style="position:absolute;top:8%;left:20%;font-size:22px;color:black;">Obtuse Triangle</p>
        <p id="heading17"style="position:absolute;top:42%;left:30%;font-size:20px;color:black;">a>90degree.</p>
        <input type="text" value ="" id="oppsite1" style="position:absolute;width:8%;height:4%;left:48%;top:38%;outline:none;border:none;font-size:25px;background-color:transparent;" placeholder="b"required>
        <input type="text" value ="" id="oppsite2" style="position:absolute;width:8%;height:4%;left:58%;top:28%;outline:none;border:none;font-size:25px;z-index:16;background-color:transparent;" placeholder="h"required>
        <input type="text" value ="" id="oppsite6" style="position:absolute;width:8%;height:4%;left:71%;top:23%;outline:none;border:none;font-size:25px;z-index:16;background-color:transparent;" placeholder="c"required>
        <input type="text" value ="" id="oppsite7" style="position:absolute;width:8%;height:4%;left:36%;top:23%;outline:none;border:none;font-size:25px;z-index:16;background-color:transparent;" placeholder="a"required>
        <button style="position:absolute;height:20px;left:58%;top:39%;">sol</button>
    </form>
    <div id="raitresult43"style="position:absolute;top:55%;left:30%;font-size:20px;color:#878787;"></div>
    <div id="step6.1"style="position:absolute;top:60%;left:30%;font-size:20px;color:#878787;"></div>
    <div id="obtuseresult"style="position:absolute;top:70%;left:30%;font-size:20px;color:#878787;"></div>
    <div id="stepfine"style="position:absolute;top:75%;left:30%;font-size:20px;color:#878787;"></div>
</div>

<p id="heading19"style="position:absolute;top:-1%;left:30%;font-size:28px;color:blue;">Different types of triangle in angle method.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I have some code in triangle shape calculator that generates CSS code used to draw the triangle shape. But I want to draw the different shapes in the triangle using canvas method. How can I change the programming code in CSS to canvas?

Comment: Not what you're asking, but in your current code the acute and obtuse triangles both look like right-angle triangles.

Comment: https://www.kirupa.com/html5/drawing_triangles_on_the_canvas.htm //this link may helpful to you

Comment: @pram All 3 of your answers are correct. For each desired triangle: `beginPath + moveTo + lineTo + lineTo`. You have to repeat this pattern for each of your 3 triangles. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Triangle Canvas Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<script>
 var canvasElement = document.querySelector("#myCanvas");
var context = canvasElement.getContext("2d");
 
// the triangle
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(200, 100);
context.lineTo(100, 300);
context.lineTo(300, 300);
context.closePath();
 
// the outline
context.lineWidth = 10;
context.strokeStyle = '#666666';
context.stroke();
 
// the fill color
context.fillStyle = "#FFCC00";
context.fill();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

`Try this

Html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Triangle Canvas Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>



</body>
</html>
```

javascript :

```
    var canvasElement = document.querySelector("#myCanvas");
var context = canvasElement.getContext("2d");

// the triangle
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(100, 100);
context.lineTo(100, 300);
context.lineTo(300, 300);
context.closePath();

// the outline
context.lineWidth = 10;
context.strokeStyle = '#666666';
context.stroke();

// the fill color
context.fillStyle = "#FFCC00";
context.fill();
```

Comment: it ok but how to draw multiple shapes of triangle in cavas.

Comment: check the below link
[multiple triangles](https://jsfiddle.net/1pkwu28k/)

Comment: @pram - To draw multiple triangles, take the code shown in this answer and repeat it or put it in a loop to draw as many triangles as you like at whatever coordinates you like.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      
      <style>
         #test {
            width: 100px;
            height:100px;
            margin: 0px auto;
         }
      </style>
      
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function drawShape(){
            var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
            
            if (canvas.getContext){
            
               var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            
               ctx.beginPath();
               ctx.moveTo(25,25);
               ctx.lineTo(105,25);
               ctx.lineTo(25,105);
               ctx.fill();
            
               ctx.beginPath();
               ctx.moveTo(125,125);
               ctx.lineTo(125,45);
               ctx.lineTo(45,125);
               ctx.closePath();
               ctx.stroke();
            }
}
          
      </script>
   </head>
   
   <body id="test" onload="drawShape();">
      <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
   </body>
   
</html>
```

Comment: it ok but how to multiple shapes are drawn in triangle i added my css codeing result shown. that modal how to draw please help me.

Comment: i want  to single page to shown three triangle shape. how to canvas programming in that method.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function draw() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  if (canvas.getContext){
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(75,50);
    ctx.lineTo(100,75);
    ctx.lineTo(100,25);
    ctx.fill();
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
 <body onload="draw();">
   <canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
 </body>
</html>
```

You can reffer following artice-[Drawing shapes in canvas.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes)

Comment: I need three triangles in single page.